# Why does the Doctor want you to subscribe to the official Doctor Who YouTube channel?

Tags: doctor-who

Most of the *Doctor Who* trailers by Peter Capaldi and the ones I've seen by the new Jodie Whitaker Doctor have the Doctor asking at the end of the YouTube video to subscribe.

Why would the Doctor want me to subscribe to the official *Doctor Who* website when the Doctor shouldn't be able to know there's a *Doctor Who* website to begin with?

Comment: For whoever is voting to close this as off topic, it isn't. Whilst it should be fine as is it would also fall under behind the scenes and fandom information and is on topic.

Comment: Just what does this have to do with Doctor Who? It's just the usual bit you get on many Youtube videos asking you to subscribe to whatever channel a video is from

Comment: Don't forget to buy a [Pr1me](https://youtu.be/iJeu3LCo-6A).

Comment: It's not off-topic, it's just poorly researched. The current *actor* films those segments for the end of the YouTube videos as a promo, and at no point do they say "Hello I'm the Doctor". The Doctor isn't asking you to subscribe, the actor is, out-of-universe.

Answer (score 6):

It is clearly not Canon and is just a publicity ploy using the actor.

Comment: Clearly the right answer, but answering such a poor, low-quality and badly-researched question is detrimental to the site.